# Flutter - Making DataTable responsive according to screen orientation/size

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to make my data table in Flutter more responsive by adjusting the width according to screen resolution (eg: in browser, its the default width, and in phone screen, its sized smaller to fit the screen). I am unable to find anything conclusive online, and most of the flex and responsive table widgets options are only available in the **Table** widget in Flutter and not **DataTable**.

The following is a snippet of how my code is structured:

```
SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: DataTable(
              columnSpacing: 0.0,
              columns: const [
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "First Name",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "Last Name",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "Username",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "Email ID",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "DOB",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "Account Type",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "Actions",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "Posts",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              rows: users
                  .map(
                    (user) => DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text(user.first_name,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        DataCell(Text(user.last_name,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        DataCell(Text(user.username,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        DataCell(Text(user.email,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        DataCell(Text(user.date_of_birth,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        DataCell(Text(user.account_type,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        DataCell(
.
.
.
.
```

If possible I would like to continue working with DataTables for this application, as it is more suitable for the system than the Table widget.

Answer (score 1):

did you try with?

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width //to get the width of screen
```

it takes width as dynamic according to device

Comment: Could you provide a complete answer and why that will be it? As your way to measure the entire screen has no difference from double.infinity which matches the full width of the screen.

Comment: As the above commentor mentioned, the answer is not complete, the table does not resize according to the screen orientation.

Comment: as far as i get he wants "width according to screen resolution",so in reference to that, 
please check this  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489513/whats-the-difference-between-double-infinity-and-mediaquery

another approach for the problem can be : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698700/datatable-column-width-issues

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar problem a few weeks ago. The [data_table_2](https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2) plugin allows me to solve this problem. Your column are more responsive according to screen resolution.

Comment: This library worked for me. It has already abstracted a lot of the "busywork" required to make data tables responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrapped the DataTable with FittedBox, Expanded and Row and it works.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: DataTable(
          columns: columns,
          rows: rows,
        ),
      ),
   ],
),
```

Comment: It works for me very well. Thanks a lot.